# Will tags of new Stack Exchange sites also be sponsored?

Tags: support, sponsored-tags, stackexchange-2.0

And who will decide which tags may be sponsored by whom? Could this be made a per-site decision?

Comment: I was thinking yesterday on the gaming beta that gog would make a great sponsor for the "retro-gaming" tag.

Comment: beat me to the question by 5 hours.  Very impressive.

Comment: I like my time zone :)

Comment: In case of the gaming site, it shouldn't be too hard to get them sponsered. [EA] [Activision] [Call of Duty] etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advertising is many, many months down the road for any new SE 2.0 sites. As in 6-12 months minimum.

Comment: so I'll ask again in 6-12 weeks ;-)