# Will tags on Stack Exchange sites be sponsorable?

Tags: discussion, sponsored-tags, stackexchange-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will tags of new SE-sites also be sponsored?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56377/will-tags-of-new-se-sites-also-be-sponsored)

Will tags on Stackexchange 2.0 sites be sponsored?  I hope so, as seeing Nintendo owning the `nes`, `snes`, and `wii` tags on Gaming would be awful cool.

Comment: This was asked this morning at: [Will tags of new SE-sites also be sponsored?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56377/will-tags-of-new-se-sites-also-be-sponsored). Jeff's statement is that advertisement will be *many* months down the road.

Comment: Cool, maybe, but unlikely - same reason Microsoft doesn't own any of the Microsoft tags on Stack Overflow.  They don't *need* the publicity. ;)